# Overwrite binary operators in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Hello I have a Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(left, right), so I want to evaluate string or domain types with data like :

```
002-1400
```

so when I use GreaterThanOrEqual operator ">=", I will be able to say `002-1400 "is greater or equal than" 002-1400, 002-1399, 002-1398 ...` So I can play with some grid rows for compare via input parameters.

Hopes be understandable,

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot define operators on the String class.  You can however create your own type and define equality relationships in any way you chose.

Comment: I have to create for example MyExpressions.GreaterThanOrEqual(p1,p2), and extends it from System.Linq.Expression thats right?

Answer (score 1):

You would override it something like this:

```
public static operator >=(Foo foo1, Foo foo2)
{
    //code here...
}
public static operator ==(Foo foo1, Foo foo2)
{
    return foo1.Equals(foo2);
}
//etc... don't forget to implement Equals and GetHashCode!
```

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode) for hashcode implementing ideas.

Edit: Ed Swangren is right, you can't override an operator on a builtin class. You can, however, override it on your own classes!

Answer (score 0):

Look for operator overloading.
See [MSDN: Operator Overloading Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28VS.71%29.aspx) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can to use [operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467.aspx). See this link for a tutorial.